# Relatórios com Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, relatório

Olá, gostaria de saber algumas opções de relatórios com Asp.Net MVC.

Tentei usar o ReportViewer mas ele fica tipado com o banco e não da para usar com objetos.

Alguém teria alguma sugestão?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obrigado a todos pelas boas sugestões que recebi, mas acabei optando por gerar os relatórios em HTML e estou utilizando o MvcRazorToPdf para gerar os pdfs.

Link do projeto no GitHub: https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf

Answer (score 9):

Sim. Algumas.

- [RazorPDF2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF2/);
- [MvcReportViewer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcReportViewer/);
- [Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa);
- [ASP.NET MVC Reports (DevExpress)](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxReportDemos).

Comment: Não conhecia o Rotativa, o mesmo já está Favoritado.

Answer (score 4):

Uma biblioteca que utilizo é a **selectpdf**, que possibilita gerar relatórios em pdf a partir de documentos html com estilização css, facilitando bastante a formatação do relatório gerado.

Ela tem uma documentação bem extensa que pode ser encontada no seu próprio site em http://selectpdf.com/pdf-library-for-net/, e também você pode utiliza-lá com sua versão free ou sua versão comercial, a versão free vez com algumas limitações, mas em si dá para fazer bastante coisa com ela.

Exemplo:

```
// create a new pdf document
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

// add a new page to the document
PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();

// create a new pdf font
PdfFont font = doc.AddFont(PdfStandardFont.Helvetica);
font.Size = 20;

// create a new text element and add it to the page
PdfTextElement text = new PdfTextElement(50, 50, "Hello world!", font);
page.Add(text);

// save pdf document
doc.Save(Response, false, "Sample.pdf");

// close pdf document
doc.Close();
```

Utilizando ela, um problema que você pode vir a ter e na hora de renderizar página html com algum model, e para resolver esse problema você pode utilizar a biblioteca RazorEngine.

Exemplo:

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

Comment: Preçinho salgado eim...ainda mais com o dólar em alta

Comment: Sim, realmente é um pouco caro, mas em si tirando suas limitações utilizando sua versão free, dar para fazer bastante coisas com ele.

Answer (score 4):

Eu gosto do iTextShap. É gratuito e facil de usar.
Tenho um código de exemplo com mvc no github.
Código fonte do exemplo:
https://github.com/rogermedeirosdasilva/Exemplos/blob/master/VSBS_ReportPDF/Report_PDF.zip

Videos explicando o uso e criação de classe para reuso.
https://youtu.be/owQ8Xj6gGvg