# Como abrir o relatório RazorPDF em uma guia separada

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

Como faço para exportar um relatório PDF com RazorPDF em **uma guia separada** ? 
O relatório **abre na mesma guia do sistema**, ou seja fica somente uma guia e se eu quiser acessar o sistema tenho que clicar no **botão Voltar do browser**.
Eu segui esse post aqui: [Como exportar uma página HTML/C#(Razor) para PDF?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94696/relat%C3%B3rios-com-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema em questão não tem a menor relação com `geração-de-pdf`, `asp.net-mvc` ou com o `RazorPDF`.

o que você precisa é abrir um link em outra aba, para tal você pode setar o `target`da sua `tag <a />` para `_blank`.

**HTML**

```
<a href='@Url.Action("action", "controle", params)' target='_blank' >Relatorio</a>
```

**Razor Engine**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Relatorio", "action", "controle", params, new { @target = "_blank" })
```