# Abrir PDF no browser automaticamente após download

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pechkin

O downalod do PDF é **executado corretamente** (fica minimizado no canto inferior do browser).

Como faze-lo abrir **automaticamente** em uma **nova guia** ?:

```
<a href="#" class="download" name="downloaditem" id="downloaditem3" target="_blank"><span style="cursor:pointer"><font color="red"><b>BAIXADA</b></font></span></a>
```

Essa dúvida é parecida com essa  [Como abrir o relatório RazorPDF em uma guia separada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161111/como-abrir-o-relat%C3%B3rio-razorpdf-em-uma-guia-separada), porém estou a usar um outro gerador de PDF  [Pechkin](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin), eu adicionei a `target="_blank"` no link conforme acima, mas não funciona.

Esta é a Action que gera o PDF:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PDFUmDocSelecionado(ProcessamentoRegistros pProcessamentoRegistros)
        {
            try
            {
                string _nomeArquivo = "Meu_Documento_" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(" ", "_").Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_") + ".pdf";
                DataTable _Dt = new DataTable();

                _Dt = _IRepositorio.ObterHTML(pProcessamentoRegistros);
                DataRow foundRow = _Dt.Rows[0];

                var pechkin = Factory.Create(new GlobalConfig());
                var pdf = pechkin.Convert(new ObjectConfig()
                                                .SetLoadImages(true).SetZoomFactor(1)
                                             .SetPrintBackground(true)
                                             .SetScreenMediaType(true)
                                             .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
                                             .SetIntelligentShrinking(true).SetCreateInternalLinks(true)
                                             .SetAllowLocalContent(true), foundRow.ItemArray[0].ToString());
                using (MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
                }

                byte[] arquivo = pdf;

                //Response.Clear();
                //Response.ClearContent();
                //Response.ClearHeaders();
                //Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                ////Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=arquivo.pdf, size={0}", _pdf.Length));
                //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline;filename=" + _nomeArquivo + ", size={0}", pdf.Length));
                //Response.BinaryWrite(pdf);
                //Response.Flush();
                //Response.End();

                ////return RedirectToAction("Index", "Documento");
                return File(arquivo, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, _nomeArquivo);
            }
            catch
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "ProcessamentoRegistros");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de retornar `File`, retorne [`FileStreamResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult(v=vs.118).aspx). Como o arquivo está em `byte[]`, precisará fazer isso para passar para [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
byte[] arquivo = pdf;
MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
pdfStream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);
pdfStream.Position = 0;
return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
```

No código que colocou de exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PDFUmDocSelecionado(ProcessamentoRegistros pProcessamentoRegistros)
{
    try
    {
        string _nomeArquivo = "Meu_Documento_" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(" ", "_").Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_") + ".pdf";
        DataTable _Dt = new DataTable();

        _Dt = _IRepositorio.ObterHTML(pProcessamentoRegistros);
        DataRow foundRow = _Dt.Rows[0];

        var pechkin = Factory.Create(new GlobalConfig());
        var pdf = pechkin.Convert(new ObjectConfig()
                                        .SetLoadImages(true).SetZoomFactor(1)
                                     .SetPrintBackground(true)
                                     .SetScreenMediaType(true)
                                     .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
                                     .SetIntelligentShrinking(true).SetCreateInternalLinks(true)
                                     .SetAllowLocalContent(true), foundRow.ItemArray[0].ToString());
        using (MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
        }

        byte[] arquivo = pdf;

        MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
        pdfStream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);
        pdfStream.Position = 0;
        return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "ProcessamentoRegistros");
    }
}
```

Abaixo um outro exemplo usando um trecho de uma resposta que dei pra outra questão sua:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OpenPdfFileInBrowser()
{
    var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
    var minhaStringHTML = @"<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><body><FORM method='post'><table><tr><td>Nome:</td><td>JOÃO DA SILVA</td></tr><tr><td>NOME:</td><td>MARCOS ALVES</td></tr></table></FORM></BODY></HTML>";

    doc.Open();
    using (var srHtml = new StringReader(minhaStringHTML))
    {
        //Convertendo o HTML
        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pw, doc, srHtml);
    }
    doc.Close();

    MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
    pdfStream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);
    pdfStream.Position = 0;
    return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
}
```

#### Veja funcionando:

[**Usei o mesmo projeto do GitHub de antes e adicionei um exemplo para abrir o PDF no navegador.**](https://github.com/Wurthma/Exemplo_PDF_ZIP)

Comment: obrigado pela resposta mas o exemplo que está no **GitHub** da erro quando clica no botão pra fazer o PDF download: `Não é possível acessar um fluxo fechado.`

Comment: @AdrianoSUV, testa agora, fiz uma edição e subi uma alteração no GitHub.

Comment: tudo certo ! Parabéns !

Answer (score 0):

Serviu aqui comigo, variável "arquivo" trago o nome dele.

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('../files/Reports/" + arquivo + "','_blank')", true);
```