# Como ler/abrir um arquivo em FTP via C#

Tags: c#, ftp

Meu cenário é um `app` onde preciso abrir um arquivo em .PDF; não fazer o download, quero abri-lo direto.

encontrei varios tutoriais onde ensinam a Uploads e Downloads, mas nenhum que mostra como ler direto.

Comment: Você tem que baixar o PDF e depois abri-lo, FTP é tranferencia, entendeu?

Comment: Se vc quer dizer por "baixar" salvar em uma pasta não precisa, mas não tem como você obter os dados do pdf sem "baixar" do ftp, como mencionou o @VirgilioNovic, mas qualquer exemplo que você encontre, ao ler (baixar) os dados do ftp, você já terá um `Stream` com os dados, basta jogar esse `Stream` para um navegador por exemplo que já será possível visualizar o pdf (precisa obter os bytes)

Comment: Sim, compreendo, achei que tivesse um meio mais prático e direto, como acessar um arquivo atravez de um url. ex: ftp://user@ftp.empresa.com/NotasNF/danfes/nomedoaquivo.pdf ... Claro que validando o acesso com as credenciais User e Pass.

Comment: ter como tem, mas não por FTP

Comment: dê uma olhada nessa biblioteca, já utilizei ela muitas vezes para operações desse tipo. https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library

Comment: [Aqui você tem um exemplo de como abrir o PDF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210340/35358). Você não especificou se é Web, MVC, Form, mas talvez sirva como exemplo. Mas antes de fazer isso vc precisar armazenar o arquivo que está no FTP em um Stream, como o @RicardoPontual já informou. O que você já tentou? Tem algo pronto?

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann estou usando Form, a indicação do Ricardo foi muito boa sim, mas não consegui codar com o uso de Stream, então acabei fazendo do jeito mais simples, fazendo o download do file.pdf pra um diretório em uma pasta fixa e abrindo o aquivo automaticamente.